# Jquery add data-rel attribute to all input fields and remove name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to somehow have data-rel value to input field and remove name from same input field on specific class.

The code i had done so far is working to remove name from that specific field. but i can't add data-rel to that same field.

Here is the code.

```
$('.vf-sortable-holder').each(function() {
    var empty_sortable = $(this).closest('.option').find('.empty-sortable').find('input');
    var sortable_name = empty_sortable.attr('name');

    input.attr('data-rel', sortable_name);

    empty_sortable.removeAttr('name');

});
```

So html look like this

```
<div class="option">
    <div class="vf-sortable-holder">
        <div class="empty-sortable hidden">
        <input type="text" name="example">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="option">
    <div class="vf-sortable-holder">
        <div class="empty-sortable hidden">
        <input type="text" name="example">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my js code works to remove name attribute but i actually need to change name with data-rel either to remove name from html with js code and add data-rel or somehow to rename name to data-rel in the end i need it to look like this:

```
<div class="option">
    <div class="vf-sortable-holder">
        <div class="empty-sortable hidden">
        <input type="text" data-rel="example">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="option">
    <div class="vf-sortable-holder">
        <div class="empty-sortable hidden">
        <input type="text" data-rel="example">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no `empty-sortable` element

Comment: yes, thanks for noticing, in the code there is empty-sortable, i just forgot to write it here in example,i edited page to add empty-sortable element.

Comment: what is "input"? That variable is not defined anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('.vf-sortable-holder').each(function() {
    var empty_sortable = $(this).find('input');
    var sortable_name = empty_sortable.attr('name');

    empty_sortable.attr('data-rel', sortable_name).removeAttr('name');;
});
```

Also remove the '.' from your vf-sortable class name in the HTML.

Comment: was going to give the same answer, no need to go up & then down, when you have $(this)

Comment: Yes this did the trick, i just only had to change empty_sortable like you posted in your example and it worked, although i don't understand how this makes difference from what i have in my code, but this one works, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting `.vf-sortable-holder`, then the parent `.option`, then the `.empty-sortable` and finally the `input`, all inside loops, seems like jumping through a lot of hoops ?

```
$('.option .vf-sortable-holder .empty-sortable input').attr('data-rel', function() {
    return this.name;
}).prop('name','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.` in the class name(`.vf-sortable-holder`)

```
<div class="option">
    <div class="vf-sortable-holder">
        <input type="text" name="example" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="option">
    <div class="vf-sortable-holder">
        <input type="text" name="example2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.vf-sortable-holder input').attr('data-rel', function () {
        var name = this.name;
        $(this).removeAttr('name');
        return name;
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BeBu4/)